# pandas dataframe use clip on a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deep-copy

I am still super confused on how pandas dataframes handle functions applied to a slice of the overall dataframe. Here is what I want to do..

I have a dataframe (normally would be much larger and with more columns!)

```
>> df
            one  two  three
0           NaN  0.0  1000
1           NaN  0.0  2000
2  1.262950e+36  NaN  3000
3           NaN  NaN  4000
```

I want to clip the value 1.262950e+36  to some other value, say 1000, so that no value in the dataframe (except for column 3) will have values larger than 1000.

**My try 1**

I tried the following:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.tolist()[:-1]].clip(upper=1000, inplace=True)
```

but it doesn't seem to work as we get

```
>> df 
               one  two  three
7317           NaN  0.0      1
7318           NaN  0.0      2
7319  1.262950e+36  NaN      3
7320           NaN  NaN      4
```

**My try 2**

So I tried with copy

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.tolist()[:-1]] copy.deepcopy(df.loc[:, df.columns.tolist()[:-1]].clip(upper=1000))
```

which works but it is obviously too long and unreadable!

Is there a better, faster, more concise and more pythonic way?

**Edit: Dtypes**

The dtypes of the columns are

```
>> df.dtypes()
one      float64
two      float64
three      int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: I did replicate something very close with your first try and it worked, what are the `dtypes` of your columns? (`df.dtypes`)

Comment: I've just updated my question!

Comment: thanks! did you try: `df.clip(upper=1000)`? (I know it will mess with column 'three', but just to get an idea of where the problem might be coming from)

Comment: try this:  df.loc[:, ['one', 'two']] = df[['one', 'two']].clip(None, 1000)

Comment: @hkyi one problem with that is that in my original dataframe I have a lot of columns (24) and I need to use `clip()` on all of them, apart from the first 2 columns (so [2:]). But yes, I noticed that it works that way, however I was hoping for something that would work more in general

Comment: @joaoavf I just tried and it works!

Comment: @joaoavf but as you said, it messes up with column 'three'

Comment: You wanna to look df.columns, exclude some column names not to clip with, and then replace it with ['one', 'two'] at the above expression.

Comment: I think it is worth trying this: `df[df.columns[:-1]].clip(upper=1000)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have numpy, using `np.maximum` is faster than using `df.clip` in most cases.

```py
import numpy as np
      
cols = ['one', 'two']:
df[cols] = np.maximum(df[cols], 0)
```